I have a problem measuring latency on my quickFix protocol program
I'm doing a program with QuickFIX protocol where I want to measure the latency of the heartbeats when I use acceptor and initiator configurations. My problem is beacuse is measuring latency with heartbeat interval too.
I change all the params on config and on code, but I can't solve the problem. In one way it's okey with good latencies, but in the other way the latency is similiar as heartbeat interval.
My code is this:
import quickfix.*;
import quickfix.field.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MiAplicacionFIX extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Instant lastHeartbeatSent;
    private Instant lastHeartbeatReceived;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Cargar configuración
            InputStream inputStream = MiAplicacionFIX.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.cfg");
            SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(inputStream);

            // Crear componentes
            MessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
            LogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory(settings);
            MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

            // Crear la aplicación
            MiAplicacionFIX application = new MiAplicacionFIX();

            boolean isInitiator = false;

            Iterator<SessionID> sessionIDIterator = settings.sectionIterator();
            while (sessionIDIterator.hasNext()) {
                SessionID sessionID = sessionIDIterator.next();
                String connectionType = settings.getString(sessionID, "ConnectionType");
                if (connectionType.equalsIgnoreCase("initiator")) {
                    isInitiator = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isInitiator) {
                // Crear el iniciador
                SocketInitiator initiator = new SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
                initiator.start();
                System.out.println("Initiator started...");

                // Mantener la aplicación corriendo
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } else {
                // Crear el aceptador
                SocketAcceptor acceptor = new SocketAcceptor(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
                acceptor.start();
                System.out.println("Acceptor started...");

                // Mantener la aplicación corriendo
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void fromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) {
        try {
            String msgType = message.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD);
            if (msgType.equals(MsgType.HEARTBEAT)) {
                lastHeartbeatReceived = Instant.now();
                if (lastHeartbeatSent != null) {
                    long latency = lastHeartbeatReceived.toEpochMilli() - lastHeartbeatSent.toEpochMilli();
                    System.out.println("Heartbeat recibido a las " + lastHeartbeatReceived + " con una latencia de " + latency + " ms.");
                }
            }
        } catch (FieldNotFound e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void toAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) {
        try {
            String msgType = message.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD);
            if (msgType.equals(MsgType.HEARTBEAT)) {
                lastHeartbeatSent = Instant.now();
                System.out.println("Heartbeat enviado a las " + lastHeartbeatSent);
            }
        } catch (FieldNotFound e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("Session created: " + sessionID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogon(SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("Logged on: " + sessionID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogout(SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("Logged out: " + sessionID);
    }
}


You cannot measure latency like this. Sender and receiver send heartbeats independently of each other. The only exception is the case where a heartbeat is sent as reply to a test request.
